# Click to mention @name

Tags: slack

I am using Slack on a Mac but I think the web version is the same. I am tired of typing `@name` each time.

Is there a way in Slack, like there is in HipChat, to click on a channel member's name so it's pasted into the message box?

Answer (score 0):

As of date, there is no feature in Slack similar to what you need. You can add this feature request on their [support page](https://www.slack.com/contact) though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to type out the whole name, that's what autocompletion is for. Type `@` and (optionally) the first letter or two of their username. You can use the up and down arrow keys to change the highlighted name in the little pop-up list. When the name you want to use is highlighted, hit your `Tab` key. Done.